# Can you describe someone as a no-brainer?

Tags: word-usage

I understand the meaning, and to be sure I searched its definition: something that requires or involves little or no mental effort. This noun literally can have another meaning logically to describe a person, it makes sense to me. My question is, is it the right usage to use no-brainer to describe someone who don't use their brain to think at all?

Comment: An appropriate term for what you are wanting to describe might be 'empty-headed'

Comment: This isn't the question you asked, which has been ably answered multiple times below, but some terms which you *could* use for a person who is not using the brain are halfwit, dimwit, ignoramus, dunce, dunderhead, numskull, shit-for-brains, ... (I can't believe how easily that list came to me).

Comment: If I heard you say that "Person X is a no-brainer" I would first think that you had to select a person to fill a position and Person X was far and away the best person for that role

Comment: @DaveMongoose aren't you amazed at English language that empty-headed and no-brainer literally mean the same thing but you use them so differently.

Comment: @drerD I think you have similar cases in other languages as well, but English certainly has a lot of them!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Yes.

[The OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/245991?redirectedFrom=no+brainer#eid) describes "no-brainer" as the other answers say:

> 1. Something that requires or involves little mental effort or intelligence to perform or understand; esp. an easily made decision

But it also includes the definition you mention:

> 2. A foolish or unintelligent person or action.

They quote the sentence: "If a no-brainer wants to talk on the radio—even if the message makes no sense whatsoever—he or she can do it."

## But...

It's worth noting that as a native English speaker, I wasn't familiar with this definition (and neither it seems, were the other answerers), so **while it *does* exist, I would advise against using it** unless you hear it often in your region.

Answer (score 23):

No. A "no-brainer" is a decision that is so obvious, you don't need to use your brain to decide. However, it's never applied to people, but rather to the decision itself.

Comment: Although it's possible (but admittedly rare) that you might use metonymy to refer to a decision *involving* a person as that person. E.g.: "We should try to predict which of these students are likely to pass this class." "Well, Sally's a no-brainer." This would mean that Sally is either so bad *or* so good at the subject that it's obvious ahead of time whether or not she's likely to pass. Trying to guess whether she'll pass or not is very easy, i.e. a no-brainer.

Answer (score 4):

'NO' is the answer from numerous examples in the site 'Context. Reverso. Net':
'Cremation versus burial is such a NO-BRAINER when l think about it'.
'Well... the tires are a NO-BRAINER'.
etc.

According to Merriam-Webster's Dictionary:
 no-brainer 
: something that requires a minimum of thought.

According to English Language Learners Dictionary: no-brainer
: a decision or choice that is very easy to make and requires very little thought.

Answer (score 4):

You could, and in context people will understand the intended meaning, but at the same time people will be aware that you are using the term wrong. A "no-brainer" already has a different definition: it refers to a problem, a task, or a decision.

You can use your meaning in the context of sarcasm, jokes, or if you're intentionally trying to show unfamiliarity with the language.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it the right usage to use no-brainer to describe someone who
>   doesn't use their brain to think at all?

Exactly as others have said. The expression does *not* refer to a person. To further illustrate here are a couple of examples of the correct usage.

---

"Should I go to the cinema with my friends or with Julia?"

"That's a no-brainer. Definitely go with Julia - she's gorgeous."

---

"What is 2+2?"

"That's a no-brainer. I don't even have to think about it. The answer is 4."